# focus on input text in conditional rendering react component

Tags: reactjs

I have Conditional Rendering component in `reactJs`. i use latest react version, and use `MaterialUi` in my application. this component use to show a span with a text and as soon as user click on it, it change to a input with a component of `MaterialUi` and user can change the field by this component

```
import React from 'react';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { grey400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';

class InlineEditInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hover: false,
            edit: false,
            value: this.props.children
        };

        this.textInput = React.createRef();
    }

    handleClick = event => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (!this.state.edit) {
            this.setState({ value: this.props.children });
            this.setState({ edit: true, hover: false });
        }
    };

    handleBlur = () => {
        this.setState({ edit: false });
        if (this.state.value.length > 0 && this.state.value !== this.props.children) this.props.onChange(this.state.value);
        else this.setState({ value: this.props.children });
    };

    handleMouseEnter = () => this.setState({ hover: true });
    handleMouseLeave = () => this.setState({ hover: false });


    render() {
        let { hover, edit, value } = this.state;
        const originalValue = this.props.children;

        const styles = {
            label: { minHeight: '2em', marginTop: '10px' },
            editIcon: { width: 20, height: 20, fill: grey400, marginLeft: 8 },
            editIconHidden: { width: 20, height: 20, fill: 'none', marginLeft: 8 }
        };
        const setFocus = () => {
            this.textInput.focus();
        };

        if (!edit)
            return (
                <div onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>
                    <span onClick={this.handleClick}>{originalValue}</span>
                    {hover ? <EditIcon style={styles.editIcon} /> : <EditIcon style={styles.editIconHidden} />}
                </div>
            );
        else
            return (
                <TextField
                    id="EditField"
                    ref={input => {
                        this.textInput = input;
                        setFocus();
                    }}
                    value={value}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                    onChange={event => this.setState({ value:event.target.value })}
                />
            );
    }
}

export default InlineEditInput;
```

At first an span with value of `originalvalue` that comes get from its props of this component, is rendered and by click on this, `edit` state changed to ture and a `TextField` component of `MaterialUi` is rendered and I want to focus on this `TextField`As soon as it is rendered.
For this purpose, I render a `TextField` and define its `ref` property that pass input to a function with name of `setFocus` and in this function I write focus method.
But when I click on span and re-render of component is occurred, i faced with the error that said :

```
this2.textInput.focus is not a function
```

how can i write this component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)** life cycle hook

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if(this.state.edit)
    this.textInput.focus();
}
```

The reason your method is not getting the input to be focused might be due to the fact that the DOM is not yet inserted when you are actually creating the ref. More like the textInput element is created but it's not appended to the DOM. Just a hunch, not 100% sure.